# create a multi variable nested directory structure UNIX

Tags: unix, for-loop, terminal, fish, seq

Trying to create a nested directory structure `YEAR/FILE_TYPE`.

Desired Directory Structure:

```
~/2016/doc
~/2016/pdf
~/2016/txt
~/2015/doc
~/2015/pdf
~/2015/txt
```

etc...

create by YEAR variable with: 
    set **varYear** (seq 1996 2016)    # fish shell syntax

create File Type variable 
    set **varType** (doc pdf txt)           # fish shell syntax

1st failed attempt:
running echo "mkdir /"**$varDate**/**$varType**

2nd failed attempt:
for i in **$varDate**
    echo $i "/" **$varType**
end                                     # fish shell syntax

Would appreciate some help on how to combine the two variables together in a for loop to create the directory structure.

Comment: Read about `for` loop in `fish`. Or use `bash` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glenn's answer is good but the braces aren't actually needed. Also, parentheses are for subcommands (similar to bash's `$()`). So the parens in your `set varType (doc pdf txt)` don't do what you want unless you meant to run a command named `doc`. Try this which relies on fish's unique manner of expanding vars with more than one value:

```
set varYear (seq 1996 2016)
set varType doc pdf txt
mkdir -p $varYear/$varType
```

Or using traditional loop structures:

```
for varYear in (seq 1996 2016)
    for varType in doc pdf txt
        mkdir -p $varYear/$varType
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ set years 2015 2016
$ set subdirs doc pdf txt
$ echo {$years}/{$subdirs}
2015/doc 2016/doc 2015/pdf 2016/pdf 2015/txt 2016/txt
```

Just replace `echo` with `mkdir -p`.

See https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand-variable
and https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand-brace

Answer (score 2):

Start with something like this in `fish` shell.

This is `bash`:

```
ftypes=(doc pdf txt)
for year in $(seq 1996 2016)
do
    for ftype in ${ftypes[*]}
    do
        echo "mkdir -p $year/$ftype"
        #mkdir -p "$year/$ftype"
    done
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response sat!

Comment: Not sure how bash syntax helps someone using fish since fish doesn't recognize most bash syntax.

Comment: Grateful for the Bash answers!  Beginner here - and value the logic.  I can find examples of syntax conversion BASH --> FISH; where I couldn't  find a nested variable sequence logic example.  For me all of the responses are wonderful and appreciated.